# Cannot compile: "Retrieve the LoaderExceptions Property" from "NULL" for more information

Tags: c#, msbuild

So I'm trying to compile this old legacy project on my computer.

I'm at the last error before getting it to work.

This is what it says (in Visual Studio 2008 no less):

[image]

The file is curiously missing. It says SGEN which

[XML Serializer Generator Tool (Sgen.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240(v=vs.110).aspx)

What should I be doing to set this straight?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/695581ae-77e7-4c3a-bb3f-6472b8c47f65/sgen-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-file-or-one-of-its-dependences-operation-is-not?forum=msbuild) tells me to turn off Auto-Serialization. That made it work.

Still wondering why it worked on my friends machine and not mine. There should be a way to diagnose this better.